# Hibernate onetoMany mapping retrieving all the results in a chain

Tags: hibernate

Say I have two tables called employee and phone_number where employee can have multiple numbers.

I have two tables for example:

```
1) employee
columns:
id
name

2) phone_number
columns:
employee_id(FK)
phone_number_type
phone_number
```

employee and phone_number have one to many mappings with (employee_id column in phone_number acting as a FK)

I have defined following annotations in the model classes.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="employee_id")
@JoinColumn(name = "ID")
private Set<PhoneNumber> phonenumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>(0);

public Set<PhoneNumber> getPhonenumbers() {
return phonenumbers; 
}

public void setPhoneNumbers(Set<PhoneNumber> phonenumbers) {
this.phonenumbers = phonenumbers; 
}
```

Class PhoneNumber

```
@Entity
@Table(name="phone_number")
public class PhoneNumber {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
private Employee employeeid;

public Employee getEmployeeid() {
return this.employeeid;
}

public void setEmployeeid(Employee employeeid) {
this.employeeid = employeeid;
}
```

My question is When I retrieve all the employees or a specific employee I also want to retrieve their phone numbers. Currently, when I run in debug mode I cannot see the phone number being populated. I am running the hibernate in springmvc framework and I am retrieving the employee through following code:

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Employees> getEmployees() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Employees").list();
}
```

Is their anything extra I need to do to return the phone_numbers. My end goal is to display the employees and the phone number in a table format in the view.

Thank you

When I made the "fetch = EAGER" I tried to debug but I didnt see values. How do I make sure  that it is pulling the phone data?

```
List<Employees> _employees= employeeService.getEmployees();
        for (Employees o: _employees) {
            java.util.Set<PhoneNumber> a = o.getPhonenumbers();
        }
```

I found the mistake that I had made but I am running into another issue.
My mistake was that the employee_id field is the FK but it was not populated properly. However, this column is not the primary key in the phone_number table.

I changed the phone_number to be following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="phonenumber")
public class Phonenumber {


    @EmbeddedId
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEEID")
    private Employee employeeid;
```

However, I am getting following error now:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable:

I am able to get rid of this error but I am running into another interesting error. It is only selecting the first row in the phonenumber.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="phonenumber")
public class Phonenumber implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="key")
    private String key;

    @Column(name="value")
    private String value;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEEID")
    private Employee employee;
```

Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employeeid", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Phonenumber> phonenumbers= new HashSet<Phonenumber>(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same problem. solved it by allowing hibernate create a new table that serves as reference

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "employee_phonenumber", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "empid"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "phoneid"))
private Set<PhoneNumber> phonenumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using `HQL` it could be achieved as follows:

  `createQuery("from employee e left join fetch e.phonenumbers")`
- As alternative you could use `EAGER loading`. However, be very careful and consider implications.
    It could impact performance because it loads all related entities.

---

There is no need in `@JoinColumn` because by means of `mappedBy` you said how you want to join entities. In most cases `@JoinColumn` used for uni-directional relationships or when you don't have `mappedBy`.

Please remove @Id from employee column in Phonenumber and let `id` be primary key.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="phonenumber")
public class Phonenumber implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="key")
    private String key;

    @Column(name="value")
    private String value;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Employee employee;
```

}

Comment: I changed fetch=LAZY to EAGER but I couldnt be sure that the hibernate is pulling data. How can I make sure?

Comment: Execute query and check if phonenumbers collection is loaded

Comment: Eager fetch should be on the employee side

Comment: So, when I check the HashSet size in the employee list for each of the employee it is 0. My query looks like following: return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Employee e left join fetch e.phonenumbers").list();

Comment: Have you removed @joincolumn annotations? Make sure Eager loading is set on the employee side. Make sure you have entities in phonenumber table with foreign keys and according employee entities.

Comment: `Mappedby` in employee should be set to `employeeid` not `employee_id`. `mappedBy` points to the property field that owns the relationship

Comment: Hi I changed the mappedby and removed joincolumn from employee but I am still not seeing the data for phonenumber. I will continue to investigate. thank you

Comment: After correcting few mistakes I get following error now: Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Composite-id class must implement Serializable. Any Idea?

Comment: if you want to use composite id Employee should implement `Serialializable` interface. Using `@EmbeddedId` is not correct in this case.

Comment: remove @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLOYEEID") as well

Comment: Hi Shevchik, thank you for your patience and instructions. I made the changes that you suggested and it is reflected in the original question. I looked at the mysql log and see that there is a second query that fetches the result from phonenumber. However, the problem is that it seems to be fetching only the first row. If there are multiple rows in the phonenumber I didn't see them in Set? Also when I iterated through them using getPhonenumbers() in a controller using the iterator I get nothing.

Comment: I've added information to my answer. You don't need to have such primary key.

Comment: when i change my phonenumber to the way you have set I  get exception: Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:com.model.Phonenumber

Comment: Are you sure you added @Id on field `id`? in phonenumber?

Comment: I added @Id in phonenumber but in reality I dont have a column that corresponds to that. The reason being, all the phone number are required to have EmployeeId which is how I have onetomany relationship between employee and phonenumber.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the fetch type to eager ?

```
FetchType.LAZY
to
FetchType.EAGER
```

You can turn on debugging to show the underlying sql statement being executed by setting

`<property name="show_sql">true</property>`

in the hibernate configuration. Use that to check.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding another column called "id" which is a primary key in the employees and this seems to fix the issue that I was having. Although I dont particularly like the solution it works.

Answer (score 0):

To populate the Phonenumber , you need to call employee.getPhonenumbers().size(). In other words, the phonenumber collection is only populated when it is accessed for the first time and not when the employee object is loaded. This on-demand style of access is called lazy loading and is the default for @OneToMany and @ManyToMany associations.