# Debugging Hibernate relationships configuration

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a performance problem with Hibernate which seems to be based upon Hibernate following the object graph too far and loading distantly-related entities. I have seen this by activating SQL logging, and seeing that when I ask Hibernate to load a list of `A` it is loading also loading the entity `D` in the relationship `A-B-C-D`.

I am aware of the gotchas in JPA & Hibernate annotations (`@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` loading eagerly in JPA for example) and as far as I can see have correctly added any missing Eager configurations.

Before I go to the trouble of posting code samples, **is there a logging setting (or analysis tool) to help me to work out *why* Hibernate is choosing to load a particular entity?**

The `org.hibernate.SQL` and `org.hibernate.type` logging settings don't seem to indicate this -- unless there is so much logging that I have missed it! -- perhaps there is something else?

Answer (score 0):

Does these websites help you?
[Hibernate onetoMany mapping retrieving all the results in a chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856651/hibernate-onetomany-mapping-retrieving-all-the-results-in-a-chain)
https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-filter-entities-mapped-association/
https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-debugging-where-does
If not, then maybe using tool like [DB Visualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/) can help you visualize DB relationships and debug them.